# NDVI for orthoimagery in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, ndvi, multi-band

I am working on orthoimagery which I got from drone (UAV). I am wondering if it is possible to create NDVI map from it.

I was following the steps as described in this tutorial:

[NDVI in ArcGIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dH0eH8rcS-s/)

I got stuck on 1:02 min. In image properties, I was supposed to change the "Band" for Red channel from "Band_1" to "Band_5". I don't have "Band_5" - I have only 4 bands. Does it mean that I am not able to calculate NDVI from my image?

[image]

Comment: I assume your fourth channel is the NIR channel and you're trying to make a NIR false colour composite to compute the NDVI? If so, try mapping NIR as red, red as green, and green as blue.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make a NIR false colour composite to compute the NDVI on the orthoimagery, which probably doesn't have a NIR band. I wonder if it is even possible. The forth channel is "Alpha" (I guess responsible for transparency information).

Answer (score 1):

If your drone imagery does not have a "red" band (~700 nm) and "NIR" band (~1000 nm) **you can't calculate an NDVI**.

The tutorial you linked to uses Landsat 8 imagery with its specific band order and wavelengths, and unless your drone image has the exact "red" and NIR wavelength images in the exact band order (It doesn't), you will not calculate NDVI

I suggest that you read a bit about the science behind the index, and get to know **your own** data, before you attempt to replicate a tutorial, as you might produce incomprehensible data, or worse - wrong data.